# how to get additional details in soap api response

Tags: category, attributes, soap

Hi i am working on magento soap_v2_wsdl. now i want some additional data for example i want category image in the category tree.

i know there is no default method to get the detail. But i can over write the core file to get the result. Now i want to know which file do i have to change to get the category image in the category tree soap response. Thanks in advance.

i already try to edit *`Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api`* which is located in *`/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Api.php`* but it is not changing anything in the result.

Answer (score 2):

You were using SOAP V2, you must update the `wsdl.xml` to get the output for your case. you need to add "image" field in both file `wsdl.xml` & `wsi.xml.`
Dont forget to go to System -> Cache Management clear all cache.

You must over write the core file to get the result per your requirement.

File : `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api` Or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api_V2`

Comment: There is no change :(

Comment: How can i get category tree using soap. My code: https://justpaste.it/7qzsc error: https://snag.gy/b6o9Cc.jpg, can you pls help me to solve the error? @Abdul